# Symfony 1.2 - return sfView::ERROR redirects to SUCCESS

Tags: php, model-view-controller, symfony1, symfony-1.2

I use Symfony to write my code for about two years, but this is the first time I'm trying to use `return sfView::ERROR` feature.

The problem is, it doesn't work. Even if my controller looks like:

```
public function executeSomething(){  

  return sfView::ERROR;

}
```

and I have two files under `templates` directory:

```
somethingSuccess.php
somethingError.php
```

it still displays `success` view.

Symfony version is: `1.2`

update:

this is part from my debug log:

```
57  Info PHPView    Render "sf_app_dir/modules/project/templates/somethingSuccess.php"
58  Info PHPView    Decorate content with "sf_app_dir/templates/clean.php"
59  Info PHPView    Render "sf_app_dir/templates/clean.php"
60  Info WebResponse    Send status "HTTP/1.1 200 OK"
61  Info WebResponse    Send header "Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8"
```

even if I add `return 'Blabla';` which should get `somethingBlabla.php` as view, or at least produce error, it still gets `SUCCESS`.

Comment: Is `executeSomething()` in `actions.class.php` or in `somethingAction.class.php`?

Comment: Standard way, `actions.class.php`

Comment: I just checked in Sf 1.4.20 and it works without a problem. Maybe some kind of settings? Have you tried to investigate the stacktrace and find where Sf chooses the wrong template?

Comment: Yep, it works in 1.4 as well as 1.0.22 (which I have tested). But still it won't work on 1.2. More info after edit

Comment: For debugging purposes, try putting the following in your somethingSuccess.php: try{throw new Exception('Test Exception');} catch($e Exception){echo "<pre>".$e->getTraceAsString()."</pre>";} It might help you figure where your return value is being overridden. As it is, the debug log you posted doesn't show any of what is causing the somethingSuccess.php to be rendered, just that it is being rendered.

Comment: without further information, here's what i'd check : first of all, i know it sounds silly, but print out sfView::ERROR (even though it won't help); then i would output something and exit before the return to make sure you go through the action; finally, i would check settings.yml and routing.yml to see whether the error isn't overridden. Without more information, it's really hard to tell since the code you provide doesn't do much and should natively render the Error template...